# XMPPFramework not sending presence

Tags: iphone, xcode, xmppframework

Im developing an app for iPhone, in wich one of the functionalities is an instant message system, using XMPPFramework. By now, im testing it with Google Talk. The delegate is the same class that manages the User Interface. So, I got this code:

In viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupStream];
}
```

The setupStream method:

```
- (void) setupStream
{
    NSLog(@"Inside setupStream");
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self connect];
}
```

The connect method:

```
- (BOOL) connect
{
    NSLog(@"Inside connect method");


    General *general = [General sharedManager];//this is a singleton to manage settings for every user
    NSString *chatid;
    NSString *chatpass;

    //chatid=[general user];
    chatid=@"somegmailaccount@gmail.com";
    xmppStream.myJID=[XMPPJID jidWithString:chatid];

    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream connect:&error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
            delegate:nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

In xmppStreamDidConnect method:

```
- (void) xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    [xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:@"password" error:NULL];
    [self goOnline];
}
```

And goOnline method:

```
- (void) goOnline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
    NSLog(@"Presence sent");
}
```

With this, the presence is not sent. I have another google account that I try for testing (say, testing@gmail.com) and in this account the presence of somegmailaccount.gmail.com is not seen. Both accounts are connected and know each other, since I used this same accounts to develop the Android app.

Any idea about what i´m doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it! The presence is not sent this way:

```
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
```

Insted, i have done it this way:

```
NSXMLElement *presence = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"presence"];
[xmppStream sendElement:presence];
```

This way, the presence is sent without any problem :)

Comment: you can also do do `[xmppStream sendElement:presence]` where presence is an XMPPPresence *, at least it worked for me just now. XMPPPresence is just a child of XMPPElement, which is a child of NSXMLElement. See https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/IntroToFramework   Cheers

Answer (score 0):

With this code, i implement method xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
 and the program DO enter that method without any call from my code. But if i put

```
[xmppStream setHostName:@"talk.google.com"];
[xmppStream setHostPort:5222];
```

... in method connect, the program DO NOT enter that method, nor xmppStreamDidConnect.

Im getting mad.